# Display Lines Gizmos or GL.Lines in camera preview window

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would need to view the Gizmos in the camera preview window. I draw shapes in GameView through Gizmos.DrawLine or GL.Lines but they do not appear in the Camera Preview.
Currently I solved by replacing the Gizmos lines with Line Renderer but I would have preferred the Gizmos for the kind of work I'm doing.
Do you know if this is achievable?

Comment: The gizmos work only in the SceneView not in the GameView or Camera render preview.

Comment: This is not exactly true, in my editor I draw shapes directly in Game View using just Gizmos.DrawLine and GL.Lines. I tried to figure out if it was possible to visualize them in the preview camera window but actually it would seem not. What I see is the Scene View environment without the Gizmos.

Comment: `I draw shapes directly in Game View using just Gizmos.DrawLine` how? the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gizmos.html) says: `Gizmos are used to give visual debugging or setup aids in the Scene view.` I have never seen them in the `GameView` so far... `What I see is the Scene View environment without the Gizmos` .. in the Camera Preview you should see the GameView not the SceneView actually

Comment: At runtime I draw in GameView and I convert 2D coordinates to world space, Gizmos lines appear both in scene and in game view. In the preview camera I certainly see Game View (as framed by the camera in Scene View) but not the Gizmos lines. I guess the gizmos are not rendered, trying to figure out if it was possible with some work around rather than replace them with line renderer ...